# How Do I Make My Hamburger Menu Responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m running into issues with the responsiveness of my hamburger menu when changing to different window sizes. How do I prevent this problem? [Please see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkhnl.jpg) Here is what [my JS looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjPoe.jpg)

**Note:** When I run the code within my text editor, it seems to work fine. However, viewing it in a browser causes it to have this problem.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Header section */
#header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
}
#header .header {
    max-height: 20vh;
    background-color: pink;
    transition: .3s ease background-color;
}

#header .brand a img{
    max-width: 25vw;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
#header .nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#header .nav-list ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: .5s ease left;
}

/* End Header */

/* End Keyframes */
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [example]

Comment: @RandyCasburn Your request caused me to figure out what was causing the issue. Thanks! The table I set in the middle of the page has images which were too large, causing the menu to stick out for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@media screen and (max-width: 800px)` 
Click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) to learn about how to make you page responsive.